# Rails 4: Passenger errors after updating gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rubygems, passenger

I am getting some strange errors and I have been scratching my head for hours trying to figure out what's going wrong here.

On my VPS, if I try to run `rails c production` I am getting the following message:

```
$ rails c production
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/specifications/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The directory `/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/specifications/` exists and contains a bunch of `.gemspec` files. However, `/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/specifications/bin/` does not exist.

That seems to be the first problem.

The second problem is that when trying to access my website, I am getting the following error in the Phusion Passenger (nginx) logs:

```
[ 2015-02-09 16:43:59.1936 6175/7f34723ac700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 576137e4. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 29360 stdout:
App 29360 stdout:
[ 2015-02-09 16:44:49.0985 6175/7f3474514700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/dani/asia-gazette: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c29b4e0c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-qH99US.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- rails/all (LoadError)
  /home/dani/asia-gazette/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
  /home/dani/asia-gazette/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/dani/asia-gazette/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /home/dani/asia-gazette/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

This has been setup correctly, everything was working fine before I ran a `bundle update` earlier this morning.

Here is my **nginx.conf**:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58;
    passenger_ruby /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby;
    #passenger_debugger on;
    #passenger_log_level 3;
    #passenger_debug_log_file /home/dani/passenger_errors.log;
    #server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include       upstream.conf;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    # Catch non-matching server names.
    server {
      return 404;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

The output of `bundle show rails` is `/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0`. Oddly, the output of `cat /home/dani/asia-gazette/.bundle/config` is `No such file or directory`.

Could this be a permissions issue?

Again, this was all working fine for months until this morning.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you deploying? where did you run `bundle update`?

Comment: I ran `bundle update` in my Rails project. I will update the original post with my nginx config file

Comment: did you run `bundle update` on your VPS?

Comment: Yes, I did it within a shell in my DigitalOcean VPS.

Comment: have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted nginx. I also reinstalled it (Phusion passenger + nginx)  all just in case that was the error. No luck :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70583/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-danig2k).

Answer (score 3):

After a day of bashing my head, turns out that this fixes the problem:

```
$ bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct fix, but it seems to have gotten my app to work again. I am using Bundler version 1.7.13.